# Calling bash script in the same context from parent directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I want to call a script from another script that resides in the parent directory of itself, say considering this structure:

```
.
├── topscript.sh
├── env.conf    
├── leaves
|   ├── main.sh
```

I want to call topscript.sh inside of main.sh.
I want to use the source command for this in order to stay in the same console context:

```
. topscript.sh
```

Also i want to read from env.conf inside of topscript.sh

How can I reasonably do this witout changing directories all the time?
My aim is to reuse the functionality inside of topscript.sh in several subscripts inside leave folders.

Comment: From main.sh, do `source ../topscript.sh`.

Comment: I'd probably use the `/full/path/to/topscript.sh` just in case `main.sh` was run from some other directory somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the full path from root :

Say main.sh is here :

```
/root/full/path/to/leaves/
```

You can call :

```
source /root/full/path/to/topscript.sh
```

or just relative link :

```
source ../topscript.sh
```